# Adding ICO file to Win32 program

Tags: c++, ico

So added a resource.rc and a resource.h file to my project.

resource.rc has `#include "resource.h" IDI_MYICON ICON "my_icon.ico"`

and resource.h has `#define IDI_MYICON 201`

```
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
wincl.hIconSm = (HICON) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON),     IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16 ,0);
```

im getting an compiler error reading  "[resource error] my_icon.ico read 2440 returned 2439"

also im teaching myself this API. is there any good resources online? the forgers win32 API tutorial is good but doesnt explain much.

Comment: Looks like your icon file might be corrupted. Can you include some more context around the error message? (i.e. a few lines above and below as well)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [ResEdit](http://web.archive.org/web/20210519075030/http://www.resedit.net/), It is a very powerful tool for editing resources.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file name is right, probable cause has it that you need to `#include <windows.h>` before including `resources.h`.  I ran into this problem yesterday and was getting the same error codes. I also noticed that if you change the .rc and recompiled, it seemed like it was deleting the `#include <windows.h>` line every time. I'm guessing the `include` path is wrong on my machine, and since it can't find the file, it removes it.

The other reason is your icon file path is wrong.  If you added my_icon.ico as a resource and it added to your project under the `Resources` folder, your file location should be `#include "resource.h" IDI_MYICON ICON "Resources\\my_icon.ico"`

If your .ico is corrupt, which it could be, try using an .ico you know isn't corrupt and see if it works.

Hope you figured this out by now!  Good luck!